# How to activate a derived type by name?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

We got a scenario where we need to create a type by name (string). We use activator for this, but because the type is unknown at compile-time we assign it to a known base-type. But what we actually need is for the object to behave as it's real type. See example:

```
void Main() {
    // Scenario A
    ShowType(new Derived());

    // Scenario B
    var derivedType = Type.GetType("Derived");
    var derived = Activator.CreateInstance(derivedType) as Base;
    ShowType(derived);
}

void ShowType<T>(T obj) {
    typeof(T).FullName.Dump();
    RaiseEvent(new Event<T>());
}

void RaiseEvent(Event<T> obj) {
}

public class Base {}
public class Derived : Base { }
```

What this returns is the following:

```
Scenario A: Derived (good)
Scenario B: Base (bad)
```

How can I get scenario B to act as scenario A? (ie. make ShowType actually get the Derived object)

Calling `obj.GetType()` does give the type we want, but in the real situation we're calling another method in `ShowType` which takes a generic type argument, so not sure how to solve that using a Type.

Comment: Can't you use reflection to call the method?

Could you update your question with some more details (esp. of the method you're calling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `derived` is actually of type `Derived`. The problem is in generic method which takes compile time type. To make work your example you can cast it to `dynamic` to force using runtime type.

```
ShowType((dynamic)derived);
```

P.S. In this case you should take in account the performance concerns related to `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `derived` variable is declared as `Base` type and in `ShowType()` method you are working with `T` (which is `Base`), not the object `obj`.

`ShowType()` should be like this:

```
void ShowType<T>(T obj)
{
    obj.GetType().FullName.Dump();
}
```